# Looking up a dynamic value in cell B1 from a table and just select the cell in the table that contains the same value in B1

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet I need help finishing. I'll include an example below to simplify what I am asking for.

I have a dynamic cell. Cell B1. In cell B1 the macro will paste a variable. That variable could be any range of answers. But for our example lets say B1 gets the value of "Banana".

How do I write a dynamic lookup macro that will just **select cell A3** from our example, but also be able to look up any variable that gets pasted there each time I run the macro?

Table A

A1: Apple

A2: Orange

A3: Banana

A4: Strawberry

A5: etc....

Update:
For those confused what I am asking. I will paste my full macro and what I've tried. I am very new to VBA.

```
Sub HardCodeTicketDetails()


Range("OO3:PQ3").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Onboarding Ticket Details").Select
Range("BA2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'I dont want the value in BA1 to be hardcoded
Range("bb2:cc2").Select
Selection.Copy



'The following did not work: I want it to look up in column A in the_ 
'"Onboarding Ticket Details" sheet what was pasted in cell BA2 and just_ 
'select the matching cell in column A.

cStart = Sheets("Onboarding Ticket Details").Cells(2, "ba")

        Columns("A:A").Select
            Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=cStart, After:=ActiveCell, 
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)



ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False


        If cell Is Nothing Then
                MsgBox ("Error: Does not exist in Ticket Details")
            Else
                MsgBox ("This ticket has been hard coded, you may delete or 
hide the tab.")
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried? Just set a variable to the cell `B1` and use `.Find` or something like `Match()`?

Comment: As it is written, this question should be closed. If you have some code to show us, that would be helpful. I recommend looking at openpyxl if you are able to use python instead of VBA.

Comment: Match function might be helpfull

Comment: I updated it do y'all know what im looking at. Sorry for the confusion. I am very new to VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code into the worksheet's private code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If  not intersect(Target, range("B1")) is nothing Then
        if not iserror(application.match(range("B1").value, columns(1), 0)) then
            cells(application.match(range("B1").value, columns(1), 0), "A").select
        end if
    End If
End Sub
```